# What is the difference between enter/exit and popEnter/popExit animations?

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction, fragment-backstack

In `setCustomAnimations()` it takes four resource id for the animation. Not really understand them. If someone having clearer picture of it it would be appreciated if you could explain.

Let's say having fragment A add in the place holder and backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.holder, fragA, FragmentA.FRAGMENT_NAME);
        ft.addToBackStack(FragmentA.FRAGMENT_NAME);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_in_from_top, R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
        ft.show(frag);
        ft.commit();
```

And the replace with fragment B:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.holder, fragB, FragmentB.FRAGMENT_NAME);
        ft.addToBackStack(FragmentB.FRAGMENT_NAME);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_in_from_top, R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
        ft.show(frag);
        ft.commit();
```

next time if do a popstack()

```
fm.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentB.FRAGMENT_NAME,
                                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Which transaction's animation it will be running from?

```
/**
 * Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are
 * entering and exiting in this transaction. The <code>popEnter</code>
 * and <code>popExit</code> animations will be played for enter/exit
 * operations specifically when popping the back stack.
 */
public abstract FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations(@AnimRes int enter,
        @AnimRes int exit, @AnimRes int popEnter, @AnimRes int popExit);
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Let's start simple case:

Replace Fragment A with Fragment B (your second code snippet)

- Fragment B runs *enter* animation
- Fragment A runs *exit* animation

Press back button and undo the replace operation

- Fragment B runs *popExit* animation
- Fragment A runs *popEnter* animation

Now to answer your question.

You don't say if the container already has a fragment or not.  Let's consider both cases:

1. Container already had a fragment (let's call it Fragment 0) when the first operation to replace with Fragment A was called.  When popping the entire stack:

   - Fragment B runs *popExit* animation (set in second snippet)
   - Fragment 0 runs *popEnter* animation (set in first snippet)
2. Container was empty so replacing with Fragment A was essentially an add operation.  When popping entire stack:

   - Fragment B runs *popExit* animation (set in second snippet)
   - No popEnter animation runs since container is now empty